# Rails4 Association autosave does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I am new in Rails.

I have a model association (belongs_to -> has_many), but the application does not save the associated model's id in the foreign key column.

The migration file:

```
class CreatePartnerAdvertisements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :partner_advertisements do |t|
        t.belongs_to :user,     index: true
        t.belongs_to :county,   index: true

        t.text    :description, null: true

        t.string  :city,        null: true,     limit: 100

        t.integer :age,         null: false,    limit: 120
        t.integer :height,      null: true,     limit: 300
        t.integer :weight,      null: true,     limit: 300

        t.timestamps null: false

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The model which foreign key's column always 1 after saves

```
class PartnerAdvertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user,   autosave: true
    belongs_to :county, autosave: true

    validates_associated  :county
end
```

This is the view

```
    <%= form_for(@partner_advertisement) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :county %><br />
    <%= collection_select :partner_advertisement ,:county_id, County.all, :id, :name, {selected: @partner_advertisement.county_id} %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

So here, I select a county from the list, but when the parter_advertisement saved, the county_id not modified... same with the user_id...

So it seems in Rails the association saving does not work. Of course I can manually save the foreign key ids if in the controller I get the right parameter from the request.

But for me it will great, if the ActiveRecord could automatically save the foreign keys for partner_advertisement.

The controller:

```
class PartnerAdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_partner_advertisement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /partner_advertisements
  # GET /partner_advertisements.json
  def index
    @partner_advertisements = PartnerAdvertisement.where(is_active: true)
  end

  # GET /partner_advertisements/1
  # GET /partner_advertisements/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /partner_advertisements/new
  def new
    @partner_advertisement = PartnerAdvertisement.new
  end

  # GET /partner_advertisements/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /partner_advertisements
  # POST /partner_advertisements.json
  def create
    @partner_advertisement = PartnerAdvertisement.new(partner_advertisement_params)
    #@partner_advertisement.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @partner_advertisement.save
        format.html { redirect_to @partner_advertisement, notice: 'Partner advertisement was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @partner_advertisement }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @partner_advertisement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /partner_advertisements/1
  # PATCH/PUT /partner_advertisements/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @partner_advertisement.update(partner_advertisement_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @partner_advertisement, notice: 'Partner advertisement was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @partner_advertisement }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @partner_advertisement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /partner_advertisements/1
  # DELETE /partner_advertisements/1.json
  def destroy
    @partner_advertisement.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to partner_advertisements_url, notice: 'Partner advertisement was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_partner_advertisement
      @partner_advertisement = PartnerAdvertisement.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def partner_advertisement_params
      #params[:partner_advertisement]
      params.require(:partner_advertisement).permit(:age, :height, :weight, :city, :county, :description, :style, :club, :level, :goal, :weekly, :occasionally, :years, :is_active)
    end
end
```

The update request's log without any errors:

```
Started PATCH "/partner_advertisements/1" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-10-11 20:01:06 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by PartnerAdvertisementsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dVNIi2H59EuZFrlrE+1ujRzDauJdc4Kkox6TbWNzpGK1mOoyfk6U8s9B/+HzASofd7DLe8/kdn4UKKIPCepjog==", "partner_advertisement"=>{"description"=>"yeap yeapr", "city"=>"Eger", "county_id"=>"9", "age"=>"45", "height"=>"43", "weight"=>"435", "style"=>"asdfdsafdf", "club"=>"adsfdf", "level"=>"asdfdsf", "goal"=>"sdfdsf", "weekly"=>"4", "occasionally"=>"3", "years"=>"3", "is_active"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Partner advertisement", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mPartnerAdvertisement Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "partner_advertisements".* FROM "partner_advertisements" WHERE "partner_advertisements"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: county_id
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/partner_advertisements/1
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

So you can see the county_id is 9 in the request, but in the database always 1 after save... :(

Comment: Do you maybe have unpermitted parameter errors in the server log? Can you also show your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow the `county_id` in your `partner_advertisement_params`.

Just add it like:

```
def partner_advertisement_params
  #params[:partner_advertisement]
  params.require(:partner_advertisement).permit(:age, :height, :weight, :city, :county, :description, :style, :club, :level, :goal, :weekly, :occasionally, :years, :is_active, :county_id)
end
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but why do I need allow the foreign key? Cause I allowed the :county...

Comment: It's because `county_id` is defined as the name for your `collection_select`. This is actually good, since the database field also will have this name. `county_id` is the name of the paramter that reaches the controller. `county` is only the name of the association.